# Convert an ArrayBuffer[Map[String,String]] to Array[Map[String,String]] in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, arraybuffer

How can I convert an `ArrayBuffer` of `Maps(String,String)` to an `Array` of `Maps(String, String)` in Scala using `toArray()`?

```
ArrayBuffer(Map("x1" -> "x", "y1" -> "y"), Map("x2" -> "x", "y2" -> "y"))
```

to

```
Array(Map("x1" -> "x", "y1" -> "y"), Map("x2" -> "x", "y2" -> "y"))
```

Comment: You can do arrBuff.toArray

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayBuffer` is mutable data sturcture. you can call `.toArray` to convert it to immutable `Array`

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> ArrayBuffer(Map("x1" -> "x", "y1" -> "y"), Map("x2" -> "x", "y2" -> "y"))
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = ArrayBuffer(Map(x1 -> x, y1 -> y), Map(x2 -> x, y2 -> y))
```

now call `.toArray`,

```
scala> res1.toArray
res2: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Array(Map(x1 -> x, y1 -> y), Map(x2 -> x, y2 -> y))
```

See the definition for `toArray` which returns `Array[B]`,

```
scala> res1.toArray
   def toArray[B >: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
```

Comment: The `toArray` does not always work e.g. "Error not enough arguments for toArray. Unspecified value parameter evidence$2".

Answer (score 1):

If you want Scala's immutable Array and immutable Map then

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer    
ArrayBuffer(Map("x1" -> "x", "y1" -> "y"), Map("x2" -> "x", "y2" -> "y")).toArray
```